# How To Make A Userform Add Data To The Same Cells In All Visible Worksheets In a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How can I make my Userform add data to the same cells in all visible worksheets in my workbook. Also, how can I create a userform button to delete all this data from all visible worksheets in my workbook.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Unprotect Password:="Tech1987!"

With ws
    .Range("C5") = CDbl(Me.tbRev)
    .Range("C6") = CDbl(Me.tbCost)
End With

Me.tbRev.Value = ""
Me.tbCost.Value = ""

ws.Protect Password:="Tech1987!"

End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/loop-thru-all-visible-sheets.1001265/

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Loop Through Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                .Unprotect Password:="Tech1987!"
                .Range("C5") = CDbl(Me.tbRev)
                .Range("C6") = CDbl(Me.tbCost)
                .Protect Password:="Tech1987!"
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
    
    Me.tbRev.Value = ""
    Me.tbCost.Value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                .Unprotect Password:="Tech1987!"
                .Range("C5:C6").Value = Empty
                .Protect Password:="Tech1987!"
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```